# Optimization of a timeline builder function

Tags: python, loops, timeline

I've got a squared signal with a frequency f, and I'm interested in the time at which the square starts.

```
def time_builder(f, t0=0, tf=300):
    """
    Function building the time line in ms between t0 and tf with a frequency f.
    f: Hz
    t0 and tf: ms
    """

    time = [t0]                         # /!\ time in ms
    i = 1
    while time[len(time)-1] < tf:
        if t0 + (i/f)*1000 < tf:
            time.append(t0 + (i/f)*1000)
        else:
            break
        i += 1
    return time
```

So this function loops between t0 and tf to create a list in which is the timing at which a square starts. I'm quite sure it's not the best way to do it, and I'd like to know how to improve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Square of what?Could you produce example?

Comment: A squared signal = squared waveform. One square is a pulse, and I am creating a list of the time at which a pulse starts (t0, t0 + T, t0 + 2*T, ....) https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/fYSMxfziqL0X7iIGx_QCZcUj7vMjpD9nBAATy9F2Jr4jvPfGYopg2Bnnr6sbPzS01D0aDp51GcP7lwqdltgzHZ5_fCIZDauFGa3n-hC_eyxdQBEMqxqyb8F4REqcXg

Comment: @Mathieu `t0` is always `0` right ? then why `t0 +` in those two places ?

Comment: No t0 default value is 0, but I'm not using always the default parameter.

Comment: That's ok , does the `t0`'s value change ? if not you can remove `t0+` both here`if t0 + (i/f)*1000 < tf:
            time.append(t0 + (i/f)*1000)` rigtht ? That doesn't affect the results

Comment: Well if my signal starts at 0 with a period of 2 ms: (0, 2, 4, 6, 8, ...)      and if it starts at 1 with a period of 2 ms: (1, 3, 5, 7, 9, ...) So yeah it does change the result. Though I could add the t0 delay with a list comprehension, would it be more efficient ?

Comment: @Mathieu thats make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am interpreting this correct, you are looking for a list of the times of the waves, starting at t0 and ending at tf.

```
def time_builder(f, t0=0, tf=300):
    """
    Function building the time line in ms between t0 and tf with a frequency f.
    f: Hz
    t0 and tf: ms
    """
    T = 1000 / f # period [ms]
    n = int( (tf - t0) / T + 0.5 ) # n integer number of wavefronts, +0.5 added for rounding consistency
    return [t0 + i*T for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: That is exactly it! I was indeed looking for a solution like that. Thanks!

Comment: There is a slight problem thou, the n isn't right all the time. If you take t0 = 1.65, tf = 200, and f = 100, your solution will miss one value. But if you take t0 = 1.65, tf = 200 and f = 60, it's correct. I don't see what is the condition on which the n parameter depends.

Comment: @Mathieu if you convert a number to an integer in python, it will always round it down, e.g. 2.7 becomes 2. Add a + 0.5 before the flooring and everything should be okay again.

Comment: Yeah, I know that this was the issue, thou how did you choose the +0.5 ? It might make one point too much in some case and all the problem lies into finding the correct value. Anyway, issue solved with a np.arange.

Comment: @Mathieu I'm gonna leave that one to the reader to think about ;) But I'm glad you found your solution after all!

Answer (score 1):

Using standard library python for this might not be the best approach... particularly considering that you might want to do other things later on.

An alternative is to use `numpy`. This will let you to do the following

```
from numpy import np
from scipy import signal

t = np.linspace(0, 1, 500, endpoint=False)
s = signal.square(2 * np.pi * 5 * t)  # we create a square signal usign scipy
d = np.diff(s)  # obtaining the differences, this tell when there is a step. 
                # In this particular case, 2 means step up -2 step down.
starts = t[np.where(d == 2)]  # take the times array t filtered by which
                              # elements in the differences array d equal to 2
```

Comment: I'll try it, but I think I'll stay on the first solution. Changing the data structures would bring many changes to the core of my program. I'm looking at combinations of 5 square waveforms with different frequencies, and at how much the pulses are overlapping. Do you know any library that could help me implement that? (my solution works and is fast to check if 5 waveforms overlap, but once I look to optimize the overlapping by adding a constant shift between pulses + a frequency jitter of +/- 5 Hz on each waveform, the computation takes hours...)

Comment: Sure, this is more of a suggestion. But using `numpy` will give you more scaling and probably a better way to represent your computations than pure python.